# If condition is being met when it should not be

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am running an `if-statement` to check if a file upload input is not empty. I am checking the `fileNameVal` with the following code `if (fileNameVal != null) {`. It seems to be always running true when it should not if a file input does not have anything within it.

The `fileShow.text()` code line is always displaying.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
var fileShow = $('#fileUploadMessage');
 fileShow.hide();
 var fileNameVal = '';
     
    $('#uploadedFileTest').change(function () {
  fileNameVal = $('#uploadedFileTest').val();
  console.log(fileNameVal);
 });
    
    
    $("form#submit").submit(function (e) {
        $.LoadingOverlay("show");
         if (fileNameVal != null) {
   fileShow.text('Please wait while your file uploads.');
   fileShow.show();
  }
    });
```

```css
#fileUploadMessage {
     position: fixed;
        bottom: 20vh;
     left: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);transform: translateX(-50%);
     color: #000;
     font-size: 3rem;
     font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
     letter-spacing: .2rem;
     text-align: center;
     display: block;
     z-index: 9999999999999999999999999999999999999;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="submit">
     <input id="first_name" type="text">
     <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" class="inputfile" id="uploadedFileTest" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple>
     <p id="fileStatus">Upload File</p>
     <button type="submit">SEND</button>
    </form>
    <p id="fileUploadMessage"></p>
```

Comment: well the value is not going to be null ever so there would be one problem. You set it to an empty string so `"" !== null`

Comment: The `change` handler here is completely redundant. Just read the filename on the server, or in the `submit` event, if you *really* have to.

Comment: have you checked what the value of fileNameVal is? it might be '' or undefined instead of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize it to null, rather to an empty string, so do either:

1. Replace your check with a check for empty string:

   ```
   if (fileNameVal != '') {
   ```
2. Replace your initialization so that it is null, not empty:

   ```
   var fileNameVal = null;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

do just

```
if (fileNameVal)
```

it will return false if it contain an empty string or a null or an undefined value

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the comparisons, strict comparison and what is false in javascript

basically 0, '', "", NAN, null, undefined and false itself returns false in a boolean expresion, all other literals for example: 1, "HI", {} will return true

This image shows the comparison(== or !=) and strict comparison(=== or !==) results

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ireqi.png)

whit this, you can do just

```
if(fileNameVal)
{//do stuff
}
```